# Migrating SharePoint 2007 Task List To SharePoint 2010

Tags: migration, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, migration-assistant, sharepoint-2010

I have a standard task list in SharePoint 2007, which is hosted by a third party.  I cannot do an in-place upgrade on the 2007 instance.  I have a locally hosted and running SharePoint 2010 instance.  How can I most easily export a task list from SharePoint 2007 into SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only one list to migrate, the easiest might be to create a new task list on your SP2010 instance, and use the **edit in datasheet mode** in order to copy the data.

If you have many lists to move, you might have to write some code that would retrieve the data from your thirdparty-hosted SP2007 instance via SP built-in web services and push it the new instance.